# How to work with detached object in CF9?

Tags: orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

If `User` is an entity, and I need to store `User` in `Session`, it will be detached on next request.

AFAIK there're only 2 methods to handle these detached objects

1. `EntityMerge(session.user)` - update DB with session's object (unsafe)
2. `session.userID` - `entityLoadByPK()` again on next request (more load)

Are these the only 2 workarounds?  Any other ways?

According to [Advanced Techniques with ColdFusion 9 ORM Integration Slide Deck](http://www.silverwareconsulting.com/index.cfm/2009/10/19/Advanced-Techniques-with-ColdFusion-9-ORM-Integration--Slides-Available) Concurrency with method #1 will throw error if entity has been changed on merge, but how is this useful? catch the exception and use method #2?

When to use `EntityReload()`?  I thought it works the same way as `EntityMerge(entity)` but it doesn't.

Thanks!

Comment: also asked here: http://groups.google.com/group/cf-orm-dev/browse_thread/thread/5792d3a387af18ae

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to only store the ID of the user that is logged in in the session.

Then I have a UserService.getCurrentUser() facade method that returns that user if I need it.

That way the user is always current, and never detached.

Answer (score 2):

I generally just use a lightweight proxy object (containing top-level properties only) in session and only load the full entity as needed in exactly the same use case as you've described.  Don't use method #1 unless you really want to burn yourself (experience talking there).

Comment: how lightweight? just fields without behaviour? how is it different from struct of properties like method #2?  Thanks!

Comment: +1 This is what I do (same concept as @Mark Mandel's answer and @Henry's option #2) but a bit more robust than just ID).  I have defined a UserBean w/ a small subset of info (eg id, username, fullname) from the User ORM entity, populated (Coldbox beanFactory.populate makes it a single call) and saved to session.  Any complex lookups (say child relationships) reference session.userbean.getID().

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate sessions are lazy loaded, and do not persist. So while you have the CF object in memory, they're pointing to a Hibernate session which is out of scope, for lack of better terminology. To get back in scope, you basically need to wake it up on your subsequent requests, using something like EntitySave() or EntityLoadByExample()

I do agree that wrapping in a service not only helps you avoid some of these issues, but is overall better architecturally than touching the entity directly.